# Trace ports on HP 5130 to mac address or ip address

Tags: hp, switch

I am looking for a way to trace a port on one of the switches to the ipaddress/hostname of the computer that is attached.

Currently I do it the opposite way  I ping the computer in cmd

```
ping 192.168.1.1
arp -a | findstr 192.168.1.1
```

which brings back a mac address 12-23-34-45-56-67

Then I go to the switch and say

```
display mac-address 1223-3445-5667
```

which tells me that it is on switch 1 port 4

How would i do this the opposite way with knowing that it is in switch 1 port 4

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
display mac-address static interface gigabitethernet 1/0/4
```